# Is this a valid solution for this probability question?

Tags: probability

A random experiment can result in one of the outcomes $\{a, b, c, d\}$ with probabilities $0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.1$ respectively. let $A$ denote te event $\{a, b\}$, $B$ the event $\{b, c, d\}$ find $P(A\cap B)$?

is it possible to assume that $P(A\cap B)=P(\{b\})=0.3$ or do i have to do it like this

$P(A)*P(B) = (0.1+0.3)*(0.3+0.5+0.1) = 0.36$

which one is right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one: $A\cap B=\{a,b\}\cap\{b,c,d\}=\{b\}$, so $P(A\cap B)=P(b)$.

The formula $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ would only apply if the events were independent, which isn't the case here.

Answer (score 3):

The multiplication rule, $P(Q\cap R)=P(Q)P(R),$ applies only for events that
are independent.
Actually, in many cases, in order to find out if two events are independent
you calculate all three probabilities in the formula and see if the
formula is true.

Your first idea was correct: you can see by inspection that
$A \cap B = \{b\}$ and use that to compute the probability.

Comment: i got the idea but why isn't this case independent?

Comment: Why should it be independent? Picking two subsets from the same probability space generally doesn't give you two independent events; the case where it does is the exception.